# Spline interpolation of animated scale

Tags: css, animation, math, interpolation

I am trying to understand how Adobe After Effects performs some of interpolations when animating different transformation properties. Properties like position are straightforward. It uses cubic bezier with start,end positions and 2 control tangents. But now I try to implement interpolation of scale property the same way Adobe does. I have two key frames, each contains same values for scale in 2 dimensions. Key1 (100,100) , Key2 (100,100) (in %). Basically,it could be just linear interpolation, but After Effects allows plotting a curve to allow easing even between two similar values. Here is how the curve looks for the points above:

[image]

Now,the data from this spline is as follows:

```
vec2 P0 = vec2(100.0f,100.0f); //start points
vec2 P1 = vec2(100.0f,100.0f); //end   point
vec2 T1 = vec2(0.06f,40.12f); //first tangent
vec3 T2 = vec2(0.95f,40.84f); //second tangent
```

It is clear to me that X value of the tangent contains time in range [0-1],while Y value contains the value of the scale,which is percentage from the default value,which is 100%. I tried to match different types of spline in order to get same interpolated values across 50 frames as in After Effects. I tried:

**Catmull- Rom**

```
  template <typename T>
  T catmullrom(float t, T p0, T p1, T p2, T p3)
  {
      return    (
        (p1 * 2.0f) +
        (-p0 + p2) * t +
        (p0 * 2.0f  -  p1 * 5.0f  +  p2 * 4.0f  - p3) * t * t +
        (-p0 + p1 *  3.0f  -  p2 * 3.0f  + p3) * t * t * t
        ) * 0.5f;
  }
```

**Hermite**

```
    template <typename T>
  T hermite(float s, T P1, T P2, T T1, T T2)
  {
     float h1 = 2 * glm::pow(s, 3) - 3 * glm::pow(s, 2) + 1;          
     float h2 = -2 * glm::pow(s, 3) + 3 * glm::pow(s, 2);             
     float h3 = glm::pow(s, 3) - 2 * glm::pow(s, 2) + s;         
     float h4 = glm::pow(s, 3) - glm::pow(s, 2);              
    T p = P1 * h1 +                   
     P2 * h2 +                   
     T1 * h3 +                    
     T2 * h4;
    return p;
  }
```

And even regular Cubic bezier.

```
 template <typename T>
T cubic(float t, T p0, T p1, T p2, T p3)
{
     T p = glm::pow3(1.0f - t) * p0 + 3 * glm::pow2(1.0f - t) * t * (p0 + p2) + 3 * (1.0f - t)*glm::pow2(t)*(p1 + p3) + glm::pow3(t) * p1;
    return  p;
 }


int steps = 50;
for (int t = 0; t <= steps; t++)
{
    float s = (float)t / (float)steps;    // scale s to go from 0 to 1

    auto p = cubic(s, P1, P2, T2, T1);

    printf("t:%f | %f , %f\n",s,p.x,p.y);
}
```

I started with Catmull-Rom and Hermite because those define control points on curve,but the results were completely wrong. Then I thought that these two are actually least fit because the tangents in this case have nothing to do with control points on curve. Cubic bezier actually gives correct interpolation in terms of value magnitude change over time. It gave me values starting from 100,with the peak at 130 (as can be seen on the graph),then descending to 100 towards t = 1. But the interpolation steps are completely wrong. Also,only Y value gets interpolated close to the values I expect. I am not a math expert.I was reading about different spline interpolations, but most of the material is completely theoretical. I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Why is P0 and P1 are both (100, 100)?  Also, shouldn't the T1 and T2 be approximately in opposite direction if they represent the tangent vectors at P0 and P1?

Comment: That's because AE allows changing value in between the two identical key frames. This curve  is a function of time (x)and magnitude (y) ,which changes the scale property.

Comment: And the tangent can be in any direction you want. I plotted those to be symmetric to help me understand how it works.